# RDF4J SAIL (not sails.js!) implementation for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, rdf4j

Has there been any work done to craft a MongoDB implementation of the RDF4J SAIL persistor interface?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such work. You might have better luck asking around on the rdf4j user group though. See http://rdf4j.org/support/

Comment: @JeenBroekstra  Thanks.  I just looked at the Sesame RDBMS SAIL implementation for overall approach and I can see why you guys wanted to shed that from RDF4J.    Lots of disassembly/assembly work!  I think the MongoDB query pipeline model might jive better with the statements coming from parsed SPARQL, esp. now with expressive $lookup.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Sesame RDBMS Sail was ancient and under-maintained, so it's hardly reflective of "the best way" to wrap a non-RDF database. But yeah, I agree with you that something like MongoDB might be easier to fit. FWIW RDF4J does have a SAIL on top of Lucene/Elasticsearch, that might in fact be a better example to look at.